# React: props.itemId returns different value vs variable that uses props.itemId

Tags: reactjs

**Currently**

I have a child component `ItemField` (see code below), that takes `this.props.itemId` from parent component, and does a check to see if `this.props.itemId` is populated, and populates a new variable `this.itemId` based on the check i.e.

```js
itemId = this.props.itemId ? this.props.itemId : "new";
```

**Problem**

Sorting actions on the App that move the position of items in the list of items around, cause `this.props.itemId` and `this.itemId` to return different values confirmed by console logs. `this.props.itemId` has the correct value, but `this.itemId` contains the original value of the item at this position.

**ItemField.js**

```js
class ItemField extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //temp value of inputs
      }
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    //no actions on did mount
  }

  //issueId to be Updated
  //if "new", then a new issue will be updated
  itemId = this.props.itemId ? this.props.itemId : "new";

  render() {
    console.log("this.props.itemId = " + this.props.itemId); //logs "1111"
    console.log("this.itemId = " + this.itemId); //should log "1111" i.e. same as above, but this doesn't always happen

    return (
      <div
        id={this.itemId}
      >{showValue}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ItemField;
```

**Question**

I have 2 console.log lines in the above script, that in some situations (e.g. after sorting the item list) return different values. These should always be the same. What are some possible reasons for this?

*Notes:*

1. *I have tried to move the `itemId = this.props.itemId ? this.props.itemId : "new"` line into the constructor and into componentDidMount, but this didn't solve the issue.*
2. *I am not mapping through all ItemFields in the parent component, but rather explicitly creating a component for each one e.g. `<ItemField value={this.props.item.name} itemId={this.props.item.id} />` where `name` is the field value, and `id` is the itemId that is passed to all fields.*

**Component Structure**

[image]

Comment: could you copy the part where you map you `ItemField`s in the parent component ?

Comment: I am currently not mapping through all `ItemField`s, but rather explicitly creating a component for each one e.g.

        `<ItemField
          value={this.props.item.name}
          itemId={this.props.item.id}
        />`
where `name` is the field value, and `id` is the `itemId` that is passed to all fields.

Comment: @Wronski kind of a shot in the dark, but have you considered moving the itemId definition inside the render method?  const itemId = this.props.itemId ? this.props.itemId : "new";

Comment: @ChristopherNgo, this is what I had initially, but thought there would be a cleaner way to do this where a reader of the code could see all the variables for the component above the render. FYI, I refactored back (i.e. variables calculated in render), and it works :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't update as it runs once, to make sure the two always have the same values move

```
itemId = this.props.itemId ? this.props.itemId : 'new';
```

to render or save it in state and use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update the value.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
class ItemField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //temp value of inputs
      itemId: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    //no actions on did mount
    this.setState({
      itemId: this.props.itemId ? this.props.itemId : 'new'
    })
  }


  //issueId to be Updated
  //if "new", then a new issue will be updated

  static getDerivedStateFromProps = (props, state) => {
    // compare props with state data
    // if they are not equal return props
    // or return null
    // more info here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops
    
    if (props.itemId !== state.itemId) {
      return props;
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('this.props.itemId = ' + this.props.itemId); //logs "1111"
    console.log('this.state.itemId = ' + this.state.itemId); //should log "1111" i.e. same as above, but this doesn't always happen

    return <div id={this.itemId}>{'showValue'}</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    id: 1111
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ id: 2233 })}>Update ID</button>
        <ItemField value={'James'} itemId={this.state.id} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I was after, but it seems like a lot of extra code to solve this (what I assume would be common) problem. What is the recommended pattern? (1) Define in `render()` or (2) compare state and props, then equalize? Or (3) is my design the cause of this problem, and I should avoid this design?

Comment: One of the things I like doing, is to not have state in child components, just access the values from props directly. I don't see the difference between 1 and 2, as `getDerivedStateFromProps` always gets called before render.

Comment: Sounds like you recommend defining these variables in `render()`. My issue is that this component contains a number of methods unique to the component that reuse `itemId` (after checking it is populated from props), and I don't want to rerun this calculation in each method. What I need is one location where it is calculated.

Comment: if that's the case use 2.

Comment: Why is that preferable to defining in `render`?

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` always runs before render, here you can compare the values and re-render if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

̶̶̶M̶̶̶o̶̶̶v̶̶̶e̶̶̶ ̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶m̶̶̶I̶̶̶d̶̶̶ ̶̶̶i̶̶̶n̶̶̶s̶̶̶i̶̶̶d̶̶̶e̶̶̶ ̶̶̶t̶̶̶h̶̶̶e̶̶̶ ̶̶̶s̶̶̶t̶̶̶a̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶ ̶̶̶A̶̶̶K̶̶̶A̶̶̶ ̶̶̶t̶̶̶h̶̶̶i̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶s̶̶̶t̶̶̶a̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶ ̶̶̶=̶̶̶{̶̶̶ ̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶m̶̶̶I̶̶̶d̶̶̶:̶̶̶t̶̶̶h̶̶̶i̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶p̶̶̶r̶̶̶o̶̶̶p̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶m̶̶̶I̶̶̶d̶̶̶}̶̶̶ ̶̶̶a̶̶̶n̶̶̶d̶̶̶ ̶̶̶i̶̶̶m̶̶̶p̶̶̶l̶̶̶e̶̶̶m̶̶̶e̶̶̶n̶̶̶t̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶ ̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶`̶̶̶c̶̶̶o̶̶̶m̶̶̶p̶̶̶o̶̶̶n̶̶̶e̶̶̶n̶̶̶t̶̶̶D̶̶̶i̶̶̶d̶̶̶U̶̶̶p̶̶̶d̶̶̶a̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶(̶̶̶p̶̶̶r̶̶̶e̶̶̶v̶̶̶P̶̶̶r̶̶̶o̶̶̶p̶̶̶s̶̶̶,̶̶̶ ̶̶̶p̶̶̶r̶̶̶e̶̶̶v̶̶̶S̶̶̶t̶̶̶a̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶,̶̶̶ ̶̶̶s̶̶̶n̶̶̶a̶̶̶p̶̶̶s̶̶̶h̶̶̶o̶̶̶t̶̶̶)̶̶̶{̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶i̶̶̶f̶̶̶ ̶̶̶(̶̶̶t̶̶̶h̶̶̶i̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶p̶̶̶r̶̶̶o̶̶̶p̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶m̶̶̶I̶̶̶d̶̶̶ ̶̶̶!̶̶̶=̶̶̶=̶̶̶ ̶̶̶p̶̶̶r̶̶̶e̶̶̶v̶̶̶P̶̶̶r̶̶̶o̶̶̶p̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶m̶̶̶I̶̶̶d̶̶̶)̶̶̶ ̶̶̶{̶̶̶ ̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶t̶̶̶h̶̶̶i̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶s̶̶̶e̶̶̶t̶̶̶S̶̶̶t̶̶̶a̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶(̶̶̶{̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶m̶̶̶I̶̶̶d̶̶̶:̶̶̶t̶̶̶h̶̶̶i̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶p̶̶̶r̶̶̶o̶̶̶p̶̶̶s̶̶̶.̶̶̶i̶̶̶t̶̶̶e̶̶̶m̶̶̶I̶̶̶d̶̶̶}̶̶̶)̶̶̶ ̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶}̶̶̶ ̶̶  ̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶ ̶̶̶}̶̶̶`̶̶̶

Why do you even need itemId honestly? Just use props directly.

```
 return (
  <div
    id={this.props.itemId || 'new' }
  >{showValue}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I didn't include all the code, but I use `itemId` in numerous methods in the component, and its easier to have it defined once rather than recalculate each time.

Comment: How about this `constructor({ itemId = 'new'}) {...` then just push temId everywhere.